# Shell command ". .profile" can not work in perl

Tags: perl, shell

I want to switch different user in UNIX

```
. /home/tuxapp/.profile
other shell commond....
```

This can be work on shell. But it's not work when I use perl.

```
system(". /home/tuxapp/.profile");
other perl code....
```

Is it *system* will create a new process ?

But how to use the common envirenment?

THANKS!

Comment: Define "not working". `echo 'echo foo' >a && perl -e'system ". a"'` prints `foo` for me, as I would expect.

Comment: Yes, `system` creates a new process. That's the whole point of `system`. `system($command)` launches `sh` and has it execute the provided shell command.

Comment: You seem to be looking for this: [how to source a shell script [environment variables] in perl script without forking a subshell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829179/how-to-source-a-shell-script-environment-variables-in-perl-script-without-fork)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a shell command to set environment variables for a Perl command, you will have to have that shell execute the Perl script. Environment variables are passed from parent to child, not from child to parent.

```
. /home/tuxapp/.profile && script.pl
```

If it absolutely must be from within the script, you could launch a shell that setups the environment and restarts the script.

```
if (!$ENV{initialized}) {
   exec('sh', '-c', '. /home/tuxapp/.profile && initialized=1 exec "$@"', '--',
         $^X, '--', $0, @ARGV)
      or die;
}
```